# How to uniquely identify a process on windows?

Tags: windows, process

Let's take for example notepad. How can I in my application be 100% sure whether notepad is running or not?
By 100% I mean, if there is another process whose name is "notepad.exe" which in fact is *not* a real notepad but for example an imitation, I don't want to detect it. Only real notepads.

I've already thought about reading the process memory but it's more difficult than it appears to be, because of memory displacements etc.

The standard way is by name, right? But for me it is *really* important, that it is not any other program since I want to interact with it what would critical fail if I found a wrong process.

Does anyone know a good way of doing this?

PS: There is no specific programming language to do it in. If possible I would prefer an indipendent solution. But if required, I specifically use .Net/C#.

Comment: Are you worried about a process purposely trying to fool your program?  In other words, is this a security problem?  Or are you just trying not to make a mistake?

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy Actually it is only about not making a mistake but that doesn't mean it is a less relevant problem. On the other hand it means, that _inteded_ fakes are not very relevant.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply the problem wasn't relevant.  I was just trying to better understand what kind of solution was needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to be 99.9%<sup>1</sup> sure you're looking at the right executable is to validate the file's [digital signature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537364%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  For example, you'd ensure that the notepad.exe in question was signed by "Microsoft Corporation".

I'd do something like this:

1. Get the list of running processes.
2. Filter down to name of interest (*notepad.exe*)
3. Get each process' image [executable] path.
4. Validate that the Authenticode signature is valid and trusted.
5. Compare the name of the signer to the expected value.
6. Success!  You can be very certain this is the correct file.

This method avoids issues like having to know ahead of time where the file should be located (which is nearly impossible – Notepad is [installed in two locations](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/03/28/563008.aspx#563177)), what its hash value should be (obviously bound to change), or strange user behavior (replacing Notepad with some other text editor).

<sup>1 - of course, it's impossible to be 100% sure.  Someone *really* determined could self-sign an executable with the expected signer name and add the certificate to their machine's root store, causing the signature to appear valid.</sup>

Comment: The only problem could be if the application I'm looking for had no signature but happily that's never the case for me.

Comment: Yep.  With no digital signatures, you'd have to fall back to collecting a list of known hashes, which obviously breaks as soon as a patch is released for any of your target executables.  I suppose you could also check the file's metadata (Product name/Company/etc), but that's very easy to fake, and also not guaranteed to be present.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I haven't been confronted to that kind of problem, but you can first check if the process is running by searching by name (in your case, that would be notepad.exe), parse the `Process.GetProcesses()` list for that, then get
`Process.StartInfo.FileName`
and see if this is the path to the Notepad executable, that would do the deal, right ?

Comment: It would be a great soution if I would know the location of the executable but I don't, so +1 but this is not a real soution for me. (Indeed the location could change. For notepad it does in fact not work but for some others, especially portable versions of programs.)

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you know of the executable we want to be running? If you knew the filesize that could work as a "hack". Use @josh3736 's method, but replace point 4 and 5 by comparing the filesize with the one you know [different versions will have different sizes, but if there are not too many you can hardcode them]. Calculation a Md5-Hashtag would look more professional, but would do basicly the same thing.

**
If your process has a GUI: you could use EnumWindows for the children to get Edit-Boxes etc. Find something destinctive for your "notepad.exe" and check if it's there.